# Li element overflow does not hide

Tags: html, css, layout, overflow

I want to make a **li** element to hide his overflow content if it is bigger than its parent. The idea is to put a logo on the left, a title the middle and a bar at the right.

This is what I got so far, http://jsfiddle.net/J5nqm/

```
<div class="container" style="color:blue;">
    <div style="float: left;">My logo here</div>
    <nav>
        <ul style="float:none; clear:all; list-style: none; ">
            <li style="position: relative; float: left; display: inline; margin-left:15px;">
                This is a really big title, its so big that breaks all my layout! How can I make this li element to hide its overflow if needed?
            </li>
            <li style="float:right; display: inline;">
                Right message bar
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

The layout in blue on the jsfiddle is how its now, and the layout in black is how it should be.

How its possible to do this with the current layout?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `width` and a `overflow:hidden` to the li element or you can use JavaScript/jQuery to crop the text and add the "...".

Comment: could also use `text-overflow` for the ellipsis instead of javascript/jquery. Here's the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow).

Comment: Thanks MarianaAFSilva, at the end I ended up using Javascript to update the title size, and if the window is re-sized I use the $(window).on('resize', function(){ /* ... */ }); to call my javacript method. Also thanks Jmh2013, I added the text-overflow:ellipsis css attribute to automatically put the "..." dots at the end!

Answer (score 1):

There's many ways to get what you want. I'd recommend looking at some examples of [CSS Float Layouts](http://learnlayout.com/float-layout.html).

If you have the information to do it, the simplest thing would be to add a `width` to your "really big title", and `overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap;` if desired. Maybe a `text-overflow` too.

If you want to guarantee that your "My logo here" shows up at the left all the time, you'll need to give it a fixed width, and give its neighbor (the `<nav>`) a `margin-left` of the same width.

You can use a similar strategy to make sure your left/right float pair doesn't overlap. If you give them both `width: 50%`, they will not overlap. Or give one `width: calc(100% - 100px);` and the other `width: 100px`. This only works these two floated elements have access to the full width of their parent, and have no positive horizontal margins. It would probably be easiest to un-float one, and give give the other a fixed width.

...or you can use javascript to layout your page. Which it sounds like that's what you are doing. Probably best to stay away from the nightmare that is CSS layout, anyhow.